# Limit of a sum with parameters : Maple

Tags: maple

I pretty novice with maple, I am working to compute a limit of a sum with maple but with two parameters.

I have

> Sum(1/sqrt(k*n-sqrt(2)*n^2), k = sqrt(2)*n+1 .. (sqrt(2)+1)*n);

So then I do,

> limit(1/sqrt(k*n-sqrt(2)*n^2), k = sqrt(2)*n+1 .. (sqrt(2)+1)*n, n = infinity);

And maple returned:

> Error, invalid input: limit expects its 2nd argument, p, to be of type Or(name = algebraic, set(name = algebraic)), but received k = 2^(1/2)*n+1 .. (2^(1/2)+1)*n

How can I do to comput this limit ?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the **Sum** in the **limit** command.

```
limit(Sum(1/sqrt(k*n-sqrt(2)*n^2), k= sqrt(2)*n+1 .. (sqrt(2)+1)*n), n= infinity);
```

Maple responds:

```
                                  2
```